# Is there a way to list output cache entries in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7, iis-7.5, outputcache

Is there a way to list all the entries in IIS 7/7.5 output cache?

I know that we have the Output Cache # Entries in PerfMon but I would like to see at least the keys that are there.

Is is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand what you really mean, but [netsh http show cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307240%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be what you are after.